# When using socket locally where the data go through?

Tags: linux, sockets

Say the system is linux, I use TPC/IP protocol. When I send data to `127.0.0.1:1024` from A process, then B process get all the data.

How does the system handle these local data traffics?

Does the data go through the network interface card from A to B?

Or they are only manipulated in the memory (much faster than network interface card)?

Comment: That is what IP routing is for. In this case the shortest route for your packet is via the local loopback device, it won't be transferred to your NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll not be processed by your network card as 127.0.0.1 address is not set on any (it's on loopback device) but it'll go through whole ip stack. Benefits are that you can manipulate this traffic with iptables or iproute tools and whatever you made that way will be ready to work between remote hosts.

If you care more about performance and use only local communiaction consider AF_UNIX socket. You can find more in `man socket` and `man unix`.

Check `man ipc` as well.